# Search Google map with marker position without replace it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here I want to create a map, where there is a search box and  default location where it cant change, and when searching for a location, the default location is not lost/change/replace.

and i want to change the marker of location where it create by searchbox with marker `parking`

here my script :

```js
var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
 var icons = {
      parking: {
        icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
      },
      library: {
        icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png'
      },
      info: {
        icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
      }
    };
 var locations = [
 ['location 1', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2,"info"],
 ['location 2', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1,"info"]
 ];

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 11,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.28747820854187),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 });

 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

 var marker, i;

 for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
   icon: icons[locations[i][4]].icon,
   map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
   return function() {
    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
   }
  })(marker, i));
 }

 var input = document.getElementById('location');
     // map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
     autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();   
     autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
         infowindow.close();
         marker.setVisible(false);
         var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
         if (!place.geometry) {
             window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
             return;
         }
   
         // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
         if (place.geometry.viewport) {
             map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
         } else {
             map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
             map.setZoom(17);
         }
        
         marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
         marker.setVisible(true);          
     
         bindDataToForm(place.formatted_address,place.geometry.location.lat(),place.geometry.location.lng());
         infowindow.setContent(place.formatted_address);
         infowindow.open(map, marker);
        
     });
     // this function will work on marker move event into map 
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
         geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
           if (results[0]) {        
               bindDataToForm(results[0].formatted_address,marker.getPosition().lat(),marker.getPosition().lng());
               infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
               infowindow.open(map, marker);
           }
         }
         });
     });


  function bindDataToForm(address,lat,lng){
     document.getElementById('location').value = address;
     document.getElementById('lat').value = lat;
     document.getElementById('lng').value = lng;
  }
```

```css
.map{
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 500px;
 background-color: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  type="text" name="latitude" id="lat" class="hidden lat-1">
<input  type="text" name="longitude" id="lng" class="hidden lng-1">
<input required="" id="location" class="form-control" style="border-radius: 5px;" name="location">
<div class="map" id="map"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

what should I change on the script? to run like what I needed?